# Exposing a .Net Class to COM, while it has a Private Generic type member

Tags: .net, generics, com, interop, private

While studing to the 70-536 exam I faced this question:

You create the following class:

```
public class HomePage{ 
public StringBuilder currentHeadlines; 
private string welcomMessage; 
Array stockTickers; 
Dictionary<int, string> priorityList; 
}
```

You need to generate a type library for this class. The type library will be used by unmanaged codes.

What member should you update?

**A.** *private string welcomMessage.*

**B.** *public StringBuilder currentHeadlines.*

**C.** *Array stockTickers.*

**D.** *Dictionary priorityList.* (Correct)

Why would be the option D the correct one, once this member is private?

I know that generic types cannot be exposed to com, but I also know that only public members are exposed. Can anyone clarify me?

Answer (score 2):

Right, the correct answer is E. *None of the above*.  For the reason you gave.  They were trying to make you see that COM doesn't know anything about generics but fumbled the example.  These sample exams always have a huge errata ("bug list"), be sure to dig it up.  [Here's one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923018), not sure how complete it is.  Having less-than-perfect documentation available otherwise models the software engineering profession pretty well.